# Filename is different to the filename that exists in DB even though a session is being used

Tags: php, database, session, file, save

I save a file with part of the filename as the session_id using PHP, like this:

```
$newFileName = 'upload_160687_'.session_id().'_160687_'.$originalFileName;
```

I then save the filename as a string using PHP in the DB and it looks like this:

```
upload_160687_l4eef6nqlekhbirv2pvmuf5660_160687_Apple_Microsoft_desktop1-1.jpg
```

However, when I look in the filesystem, that same file is saved as :

```
upload_160687_41d99tblerr1tr6qq3n854jt05_160687_Apple_Microsoft_desktop1-1.jpg
```

You can see the difference, but what the hell is the reason????

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you show a little bit more of your sourcecode to verify session_id() is only retrieved once? 
Read here (http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php#52689) that FireFox might pick up a different session_id due to using a single shared process.. Could you exclude this as a possibility?

Comment: Hhmm, I never knew that, I can not rule it out now. But I am testing it and seeing what is going on, thank you for the suggestion Tim. :)

Comment: You are a Genius Tim! I tried it on IE7 and it works perfectly but anything I do on Firefox will not work. So it is that very issue you are talking about. I know what the problem is and I can address it thank you!!! :)

Comment: Are you using a cookie or the URL to transfer the session ID? If the former, be sure the cookie is accepted.

Comment: I am not using a cookie or using the URL to pass session_id. I have different PHP scripts that are executed by my Flash Application. All these PHP scripts make use of the session_id. Do you not think that the problem could be what Tim suggested? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we confirm & close the question and mark it up to the FireFox session_id quirks due to its single shared process?